# Ubuntu provide a manual installation of a package as alternative for debian archives

Tags: ubuntu, npm, dpkg

Is it possible to point a dependency of a `deb` file to a local installation?

In the full scenario both `node` and `npm` have been installed with `nvm` but when trying to install the debian package, it complains about unmet dependencies:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 <package-name>: Depends: npm but it is not installed
```

More generally I wonder how feasible this is because if I understand correctly a package dependency is expected to be available in a location available to all users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a situation where a package has an unmet dependency, but you have installed this dependency by hand (or you know that the package does not really need the dependency), you can use [equivs](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/equivs) to create a dummy package which satisfies the dependency.

Note that this is more like a hack, so only use it if you know what you are doing and there is no better solution, like using a PPA for the most recent version of the dependency.

If you are using `make install` to install your binaries, you might also consider using [`checkinstall`](https://wiki.debian.org/CheckInstall) to create a package which keeps track of the manual install.

Comment: equivs was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!